# Best way to create multiple time differences variables

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lapply, difftime

I would like to create multiple variables to show the time differences from a variable (V0) for several variables. I would like the absolute difference (i.e., ignoring the sign of the difference). All my variables are in date format.

I have the below code, which works, but I imagine there is a neater/better way of doing this in fewer lines of code. I've tried a couple of things without much luck.

```
df$V1_timediff <- (abs(as.numeric(difftime(df$V0, df$V1, units = "days"))))

df$V2_timediff <- (abs(as.numeric(difftime(df$V0, df$V2, units = "days"))))

df$V3_timediff <- (abs(as.numeric(difftime(df$V0, df$V3, units = "days"))))

df$V4_timediff <- (abs(as.numeric(difftime(df$V0, df$V4, units = "days"))))
```

Comment: Can you provide some data? I think I have a decent solution but it doesn't use difftime at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll demonstrate using `mtcars`. Since it doesn't have `POSIXt` objects, I'll use simple `-`; this should work for your case as well, no changes, so technically no need for `difftime`, the results should be identical. However, the premise of both solutions below will work if adapted to use `difftime`.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(vs:carb, list(timediff = ~ abs(as.numeric(cyl - ., units = "days"))))) %>%
  head()
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb vs_timediff am_timediff gear_timediff carb_timediff
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4           6           5             2             2
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4           6           5             2             2
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1           3           3             0             3
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1           5           6             3             5
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2           8           8             5             6
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1           5           6             3             5
```

### base R

```r
tmp <- lapply(mtcars$cyl - subset(mtcars, select = vs:carb),
              function(z) abs(as.numeric(z, units = "days")))
names(tmp) <- paste0(names(tmp), "_timediff")
head(cbind(mtcars, tmp))
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb vs_timediff am_timediff gear_timediff carb_timediff
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4           6           5             2             2
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4           6           5             2             2
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1           3           3             0             3
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1           5           6             3             5
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2           8           8             5             6
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1           5           6             3             5
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base` we can define a UDF and loop through columns:

```r
time_diff <- function(df, v0, vn) {
  abs(as.numeric(difftime(df[[v0]], df[[vn]], units = "days")))
}

lapply(c("t2", "t3"), function(tn) time_diff(test, "t1", tn))
```

```
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.05208333 0.05208333 0.05208333 0.05208333 0.05208333
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0.1041667 0.1041667 0.1041667 0.1041667 0.1041667
```

#### Data:

```
structure(list(t1 = structure(c(1014919200, 1014920100, 1014921000,
                                1014921900, 1014922800), 
                    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                t2 = structure(c(1014923700, 1014924600, 1014925500, 
                                 1014926400, 1014927300),       
                    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                t3 = structure(c(1014928200, 1014929100, 1014930000, 
                                 1014930900, 1014931800), 
                    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```